# Turn off numbering of sections in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I tried to turn off numbering of the sections in my LaTeX documten using `\renewcommand\thesection{}`.
The numbering did disappear but the title of the section is still indented.

[image: Section with numbering]
[image: Section without numbering]

The «Title of the section» should be at the point where the «3» used to be.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much simpler: use the `\section*{Some Text}` command:

```
\documentstyle[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Some Text}

Lorum ipsum ...

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your anwer! It also removed the indentation.

Comment: The indentation was an artefact of, and pardon my directness, "you doing it wrong".  You just commented out the number, but the indent was still there as part of the default display.   The `\section*{}` command, on the other hand, _was made for this_ so it does it right ;-)